# YouTube Music Snap app message?

Tags: snap, youtube

every time I will open YouTube music snap app, this message will appear.

> "Allow settings change? Allow snap "youtube-music-desktop-app" to
> change "default-url-scheme-handler" subproperty "ytmd" to
> "youtube-music-desktop-app_youtube-music-desktop-app.desktop" ? This
> dialog will close automatically after 5 minutes of inactivity"

Anyway to fix this issue?

Comment: Bug reported and fixed but the snap update hasn't been released (15-Dec-2021) https://github.com/ytmdesktop/ytmdesktop/issues/630 https://github.com/ytmdesktop/ytmdesktop/commit/f3cbbc61585a780b309218b21dd5c939b36cfc99

Answer (score 4):

The internet is currently pretty silent about this, but it seems to be an issue related to snap, not ytmd. I've found a few similar issues related to other snap apps giving the same message on startup.

My solution: uninstall the snap app and download the app image from the creator's website.

https://ytmdesktop.app/#download

Make sure the file is executable. (chmod +x filename)

If you want this to be treated like an application(search, pin to dock, etc..), create a new file: ~/.local/share/applications/ytmd.desktop.

I followed [this article](https://www.enovision.net/how-create-appimage-entries-menu-ubuntu) and used the [icon from the ytmd github repo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ytmdesktop/ytmdesktop/master/src/assets/favicon.png). Works just as well (better since there is no pop-up) as the snap installation.

Comment: Can you clarify why/how this works better than the snap installation? Besides the pop-up what's the improvement? Startup time? Memory usage?

Comment: I'm sure the benchmarks are the same. The reason I say it's better is just that I don't get a pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled it using `snap remove`, and installed it via FlatPak:

```
flatpak install flathub app.ytmdesktop.ytmdesktop
```

The message disappeared.